# python type annotations for abstract Enum value

Tags: python, enums, typing

I have an enum

```
from enum import Enum

class StrangeEventTypeVariants(Enum):
    crew_training = "Crew training"
    crew_travel = "Crew travel"
    flight = "Flight"
    maintenance = "Maintenance"
    parking = "Parking"
```

and function that of class that process abstract enum

```
class EnumSuggest:
    def __init__(self, enum: Enum):
        self.variants = [{"id": member.name, "name": member.value} for member in enum]

    def get_suggest(self, _):
        return self.variants
```

but annotation above is incorrect, for

```
suggest = EnumSuggest(StrangeEventTypeVariants)
```

I got next linter warning

> Expected type Enum, got Type[StrangeEventTypeVariants]

How  to fix it ?

Comment: My guess is that you're passing the enum class not an enum instance, so it claims that the class is not an enum [instance]

Comment: Your code works just fine... could you tell me how did you import `Enum` and also what version of python do you use??

Comment: from enum import Enum

Comment: @Anwarvic The code works because Python doesn't care about the type hint. The linter does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing an *instance* of `Enum` to `EnumSuggest.__init__`; you are passing a *subclass* of `Enum`. The type hint should reflect that.

```
class EnumSuggest:
    def __init__(self, enum: Type[Enum]):
        self.variants = [{"id": member.name, "name": member.value} for member in enum]

    def get_suggest(self, _):
        return self.variants
```